# repeat string program in Java

Tags: java, string, repeat

I'm new in Java and i'm playing with some silly questions:

For e.g:

Suppose, I've given `ababb`..

Here `ab` is defined **two** times. So how to detect it in Java?

Another example is,

`abcabcabcab`

Here, `abc` is defined **three** times.

Comment: Most languages have immense documentation available on the internet. You can start by going through the documentation and finding a suitable API. In your case, the values are of type `String` so you can start looking at the documentation for the `String` class. Alternately, you can search the site for available answers. Both these skills are equally important if you wish to be a decent programmer.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be using the indexOf(str, fromIndex) method in String.
Loop through your string and search for the indexOf "ab", if you find it, add the result and the length of your expression ("ab") to fromIndex.

There may be ready made methods to do this also, but if it does not bore you doing it by yourself, it's usually a good training not to use them.